# Display the Employee Name (Boss) and number of Employee (Subordinates) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have a table emp having  foll data:

```
EmpID    EmpName   MgrID 

100     King        NULL
101     Smith       100
102     Shine       100
103     Racy        102
```

Now i want to Display the Employee Name (Boss) and number of Employee (Subordinates) something like this

```
BOSS       SUBORDINATES
```

---

```
BLAKE                 5

CLARK                 1

FORD                  1

JONES                 2

KING                  3

SCOTT                 1
```

Please guide how to go about querying this table in SQL Server 2008.

Attempted query:

```
select e.first_name as ename,m.first_name as mname from employees e,employees m where e.manager_id=m.employee_id
```

Comment: what do you have tried??

Comment: select e.first_name as ename,m.first_name as mname
from employees e,employees m
where e.manager_id=m.employee_id

Comment: While I normally agree with discouraging questions that show a lack of effort, this SQL threw me the first time I had to do it.  It looks like a newbie question, and perhaps he isn't even sure where to begin to try.

Comment: Guys i used that query to have a list of emps and mgr for corr emps and was not able to figure out a logic for this one.Hence i posted d question.

Comment: @techie - what query?  You haven't posted any query.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables select e.first_name as ename,m.first_name as mname from employees e,employees m where e.manager_id=m.employee_id

Comment: Do not ever use implicit joins, they are a SQl antipattern. You should not learn to use poor techniques.

Comment: U mean i shud use ANSI joins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Start by self-joining on `EmpID=MgrID`
- Group by `MgrID` and `EmpName`
- Select `EmpName` and `count(*)`

Translating this to SQL is mechanical:

```
SELECT b.EmpName, COUNT(*)
FROM Employee e
JOIN Employee b ON b.EmpID=e.MgrID
GROUP BY b.EmpID, b.EmpName
```

Comment: Though i am not able to execute the query presently,ur logic of approach seems to be right.Appreciate d help.

Comment: Can u please guide when do we actually use group by?

Comment: @techie You use `group by` when you need to "collapse" groups of multiple rows into one row per group (the technical term is *"to aggregate"*). A good (but not a 100% certain) indication of having to use `group by` is the presence of aggregate functions, such as `count`, `min`, `max`, and so on, in your selection list.

Comment: in the above query cud v also have used dis `GROUP BY e.MgrID, e.EmpName` It should work fine right as its just another instance.

Comment: @techie If you group by `e.EmpName`, every employee would become his/her own group (assuming the names are unique, as in your example). All groups will have only one member, so all counts will become `1`. You could `group by e.MgrID` instead of `b.EmpID` (a bug I just fixed in my last edit) since these two are equal because of the join criteria.

Comment: So my output will ideally luk like dis right-  EmpName   MgrCount King 2 Smith,Shine and racy with 0

Comment: @techie Follow this [link to sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fef36/4) to see how the output of this query is going to look. The query is going to exclude non-managers. If you would like to include them back, see this modified query [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fef36/6).

Comment: Thanks a ton man!!!I never knew about this interface online provision.Thanks a million :D

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
   EmpID INT,
   EmpName VARCHAR(100),
   MgrID INT)

INSERT INTO test VALUES (100, 'King', NULL),
                        (101, 'Smith', 100),
                        (102, 'Shine', 100),
                        (103, 'Racy', 102)

SELECT t1.EmpName AS Boss, 
       COUNT(*) AS Subordinates
FROM test AS t1 INNER JOIN test AS t2 ON t1.EmpID = t2.MgrID
GROUP BY t1.EmpName
```